# If $B_{i}$ denotes number of balls in $i^{th}$ box then find the probability that $B_{1}<B_{3}<B_{5}<B_{7}$ and $B_{2}>B_{4}>B_{6}>B_{8}$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

$36$ identical balls are randomly distributed in $8$ different boxes in such a manner that no box is empty and no two boxes have same number of balls.

If $B_{i}$ denotes number of balls in $i^{th}$ box then find the probability that $B_{1}<B_{3}<B_{5}<B_{7}$ and $B_{2}>B_{4}>B_{6}>B_{8}$.

**My Attempt**
I am facing difficulty in finding number of ways to distribute balls so that boxes contain unequal number of balls.Once this is done then rest shouldn't be very difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you haven't noticed, note your conditions on the number of balls in each box means that, for the minimum number of balls required, there is a ball in one box, 2 balls in another box, and so on until you get 8 balls in the 8th box.  If you add up this minimum set of balls and compare it to your number, i.e., 36, I think you will find something interesting, and potentially useful for solving the problem.

Comment: That's nice.Objects in the four boxes $B_{1},B_{3},B_{5},B_{7}$ can be put in $4!$ ways of which one is the desired outcome, Similarly for$B_{2},B_{4},B_{6},B_{8}$. So according to what you say the required probability should be $\frac{1}{4!}\frac{1}{4!}\times 2$

Comment: Assuming the probability of any particular combination is the same as any other, as is the case here, the overall probability is just the total number of ways that the conditions can be met divided by the total number of combinations available.  For the latter value, as I indicated and you apparently determined, this is 8!, due to the numbers for the boxes being the minimum, i.e., 1, 2, ..., 8.  Now, consider choosing 4 values out of 8 for the boxes $B_1$, $B_3$, $B_5$ and $B_7$.  Among those choices, there is only 1 which will match your conditions.  Also, once you choose the 4 values, the

Comment: (cont) remaining 4 need to be distributed to the boxes $B_2$, $B_4$, $B_6$ and $B_8$, with there also only being 1 way to do this to match the conditions.

Comment: All this is true, but the answer to the problem asked does not depend on it.  If there were $100$ balls the answer would be the same.

Comment: @RossMillikan, thank you for pointing out the answer doesn't really depend on the number of balls.  I didn't realize that initially.  However, note if it was less than 36, there would be no way to distribute the balls based on the requirements, so depending on how you looked at it, the probability could be considered to be 0 in that case.  As such, IMHO, it doesn't hurt to at least confirm the problem statement provides enough balls to solve it as was likely intended.

Answer (score 2):

Much easier is to use the symmetry of the problem.  For each arrangement of balls with $B_1 \lt B_3$ there is a corresponding one with all the rest of the balls in the same positions but $B_1 \gt B_3$ and vice versa.  That tells you that with the conditions of your problem, the chance $B_1 \lt B_3$ is $\frac 12$.  Extend this to a chain of four inequalities.